Growing centered div inside div maintaining aspect ratio
I couldn't find a solution for growing a div inside div maintaining aspect-ratio except for images, but I want to do it with a div.
I basically want object-fit: contain behavior for a div inside a div, with some padding.
But it only works for wide, but not for narrow divs.
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
  
  </div>
</div>

---

.container {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  width: 320px; /* arbitrary values for testing */
  height: 190px; /* arbitrary values for testing */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px;
}

.element {
  background: red;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 3;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

This code works with aspect-ratio: 3 / 1; but not with aspect-ratio: 1 / 3;.


.container {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  width: 320px;
  height: 190px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px;
}

.element {
  background: red;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 3;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
  
  </div>
</div>



My expected behavior is depending on the aspect-ratio (which I want to change via JavaScript later on, that the result looks like in the image below:
Left Aspect Ratio: 3/1; Right Aspect Ratio: 1/3

What are your expectations? 1 / 3 means the height should be x3 of width (which is 100%), but you have a max-height constraint. If you remove it, the red square becomes 960px tall (320px * 3)

I see a red rectangle perfectly fitting the yellow with a padding of 16 pixels.

I think you need a combination of container units and possibly minmax.

do not use flex or grid on the parent and aspect-ratio can be applied . the grid layouts do resize content to fit the cells if not centered, if centered, the content gives it a size. Aside, give it a max-height and max-width of 100% to keep inside its parent.

@G-Cyrillus.. can you please show an example of centering the .element without the container being nor a flex nor a grid.. and yet just using max-height and max-width please? because at those condition nor by using transform but also using the flex itself, the content takes any height/width by using the corresponding max-height and max-width. At the same time the quickest solution, given that width is less than height, was just setting the height 100% and yet retaining the flex layout for the sake of centering.

I know that such a scenario wouldn't cover the flip of which is the larger dimension (h/w) but since you know what's the aspect ratio at the time of styling you decide which one rules the 100%.

@diego here is a tricky example using very old css method   https://liveweave.com/h2TEPX (you might have to refresh the page once loaded if you see the default code, not your container/element) there is 2 example : with one and two elements inside container this method was working in IE5 ... so really old and forgotten, just basic css ;)

You say you want to use JavaScript to change but perhaps show what you tired when doing that here so that we may assist you in fixing it.  Especially since that is what your question appears to be all about here.

@G-Cyrillus I watched the demo on liveweave and I think it's very convoluted plus the height doesn't fit actually the whole available space

@DiegoD , it was not an answer just an example for you that should take any ratio and hopefully without overflowing. It is just that for plain CSS with flex or grid + place-content:center, it  won't work. that was about my comments ;) I don't either think that container queries could be of any help here.

This can be done with pure CSS for those browsers (which is all the main ones now) which support container query units (cqh etc).
To achieve an object-fit: contain effect, of the red rectangle either the width or the height of the red rectangle has to be the same as the container (padding excepted).
Which it is to be depends on the relative aspect ratios of the container and element.
This snippet uses CSS clamp to get a variable which has either a value of 0cqh or 1cqh depending on which is the larger of the two ratios.
It then calculates the resultant width of the red rectangle.


<style>
  .container {
    container: mycontainer / size;
    display: flex;
    background: yellow;
    width: 320px;
    height: 190px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 16px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  
  @container mycontainer (min-width: 0px) {
    .element {
      position: relative;
      background: red;
      --ar: 1 / 3;
      aspect-ratio: var(--ar);
      --x: calc(-1 * min(0cqw, 100cqw - (100cqh * var(--ar))));
      --y: clamp(0cqh, var(--x), 1cqh);
      /* 1 / 3 gives 0cqh while 3 / 1 gives 1cqh */
      --w1: calc((var(--y) * var(--ar) * 100));
      --w2: calc((1cqh - var(--y)) * var(--ar) * 100);
      width: calc(var(--w1) + var(--w2));
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element" style="--ar: 3 / 1;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element" style="--ar: 1 / 3;">
  </div>
</div>
<br> and with container dimensions reversed<br>
<div class="container" style="width: 190px; height: 320px;">
  <div class="element" style="--ar: 3 / 1;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="width: 190px; height: 320px;">
  <div class="element" style="--ar: 1 / 3;">
  </div>
</div>




If you want to achieve this with just css, you'll need some "hacking". For example, adding a <canvas> element that will store the required aspect-ratio:


toggle.onclick = function() {
  const aspectRatio = this.classList.contains('active') ? '1/3' : '3/1';
  container.style.setProperty('--aspect-ratio', aspectRatio)
  this.classList.toggle('active')
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  width: 320px;
  height: 190px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px;
  --aspect-ratio: 1 / 3;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: var(--aspect-ratio);
  canvas {
    aspect-ratio: var(--aspect-ratio);
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
}

.element {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <canvas width="2000" height="2000"></canvas>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="toggle">Toggle aspect-ratio</button>




Actually, no need to add an otherwise spurious element to the DOM - CSS can do this 'on its own' now.

Thanks @AHaworth! Actually, I was thinking about container queries. But I give an answer that I knew and applied self. I see your answer and will try to understand it. )) Best regards.
